# How to test rxjs ajax call with jest?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, jestjs, rxjs6

I have a container component where I'm fetching the data via `ajax` operator from `rxjs`

```
const data = ajax(someUrl).pipe(map(r => r.response));
```

And in my componentDidMount I have

```
data.subscribe((data) => {
    this.setState({ data });
});
```

// test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/ajax'
import App from '../src/App';

describe('<App />', () => {
  const wrap = mount(<App />);
  const data = [{ 1: 'a' }];
  const mock = ajax('http://url.com').pipe(map(() => data));
  it('renders', () => {
    console.log(mock.subscribe(x => x));
    expect(wrap.find(App).exists()).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

How do I go about mocking the response so that when I run the test it I can pass that data on to other components and check if they render?

All the testing examples I've found have been redux-Observable ones which I'm not using.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

First you need to understand that you should be testing ***one thing at a time***. 
Meaning that testing your async method execution should be separated from testing your components rendering proper content.

To test async methods you can mock your data and than mock timers in Jest.

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks.html

with `jest.useFakeTimers()` and techniques mentioned above.

For testing component proper rendering use jest `snapshots` and e2e testing (can be done with ex. [TestCafe](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/))

To connect those approaches you need to design you app in a way that will allow you to:

1. The API you call in your component, should be external to component and be called from that external source (different file, different class, however you design it), so you can replace it in test.
2. Whole API should be modular, so you can take one module and test it without initializing whole API just for this case.
3. If you design your app in such manner, you can initialize part of the API with mock data, than render your component in test and as it will call mocked API, you can check if it renders what you expect it to.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and the links, I'll go through them and get back! : )

Comment: The thing is with these techniques it feels like I'm testing a different implementation, I want to test the method inside my container, for which i need to mock ajax.get observable's response and test if my container invokes the call as well.

Comment: 1. The API you call in your component, should be external to component and be called from that external source (different file, different class, however you design it), so you can replace it in test. 
2. Whole API should be modular, so you can take one module and test it without initializing whole API just for this case. 
3. If you design your app in such manner, you can initialize part of the API with mock data, than render your component in test and as it will call mocked API, you can check if it renders what you expect it to.

Comment: @SinSync it s 2 years later, but can you mark it as an answer if it helped you :)? Thanks